# Blocky smoke simulation doesn't change shape or makes a dark flash

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've been trying to make several smokes simuations.

I'always end up with 2 types of results :

- 1st one  is this strange compact & blocky  smoke that never change it's shape even if going upward....

what my smoke look's like

[image: what my smoke look's like]

I've tried a few things to stop but nothing's working, changing resolution division or particle emmiter scale etc, standing still...

- Or, but still rare, that my smoke do not form anything, but when my frames are re-looping, make a strange kind of "dark" flash and disappear the next 5 frames....

PS : i'm using Blender 2.9.1 & Cycles render engine.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved by turning Node Wrangler off, relaunching and baking again... idk why .....